Unresolved external symbol using VulkanMemoryAllocator
I installed VulkanMemoryAllocator by adding a git submodule and using add_subdirectory(vma) in my CMakeList.txt.
And in the subproject which requires VMA, I do configured the link by adding target_link_libraries(myproject PRIVATE GPUOpen::VulkanMemoryAllocator)
However, I still receive such errors:
main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol vmaCreateAllocator referenced in function "private: void __cdecl hi::v1::gfx_device::initialize_device(void)" (?initialize_device@gfx_device@v1@hi@@AEAAXXZ)
main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol vmaDestroyAllocator referenced in function "public: __cdecl hi::v1::gfx_device::~gfx_device(void)" (??1gfx_device@v1@hi@@QEAA@XZ)


root/CMakeList.txt:
project(myproj1 CXX)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(hikogui)
add_subdirectory(vma)
add_subdirectory(myproject)

./root/myproject/CMakeList.txt:
add_library(myproject SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

target_link_libraries(myproject PRIVATE ${Vulkan_LIBRARY} Vulkan::Vulkan)
target_link_libraries(myproject PRIVATE GPUOpen::VulkanMemoryAllocator)
target_link_libraries(myproject PRIVATE hikogui)


Please post a [mcve]. main.cpp unlikely is a part of myproject and you get linker errors related to another target that is not shown.

Did you read the VMA project setup documentation?

In exactly one CPP file define following macro before this include. It enables also internal definitions.

#define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "vk_mem_alloc.h"


To be fair they might want to mention that in their readme https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator

It's not as if their readme is sufficient to actually use the VMA, since it doesn't tell you anything about how to actually allocate memory.  The readme just covers acquiring and using the library in your project.  You STILL have to read the docs to get in gear, so to speak.  If you think it should be in the readme though, nothing is stopping you from making a PR.
